# How to add 1 question in Google Forms which takes multiple inputs from the user and stores in a single column in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am struggling to create a custom question in Google forms which can ask the user for Multiple inputs or Short texts.

For example If I ask a question to a shopkeeper: "Name all the vegetables you keep in your stall?".. The shopkeeper  should be able to add multiple vegetable names in same question.

Secondly the responses should be listed one below the other in single column in Google Sheets.

I don't have much coding knowledge in Apps script Editor but can I make use of an automatic transpose Function here?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It sounds like you are describing your _attempted solution_ to a problem, rather than the _problem_. If that is the case, please edit the question. See [What is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet. Also explain _why_ you need to transpose the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spreadsheet formula that employs an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to transform data in a form responses sheet into a new sheet that has a row-oriented layout where row data is repeated the way you describe.

See the [Array Expression Formula Builder](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XlAbMfEhjQ1EFkGU0DH8nDFD9QV_Je48-Oz7JHuJyrI/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet for examples and instructions on how to build a formula to expand the data to multiple rows. The formula should go to another sheet — do not enter it directly in the form responses sheet.